# python: кнопка на сайте www.soccer24.com стала не кликабельна!

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Долгое время работал вот этот код!

```
driver.get("https://www.soccer24.com/")
buttons = driver.find_elements('css selector', '#live-table > div.filters > div.calendarCont > div > '
                                           'button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow') 
for button in buttons:
   button. Click()
```

Видимо что-то админ сайта изменил - никак не могу понять что! Есть подозрение, что сайт стал распознавать курсор мыши над кнопкой!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации не нашел вызова с 3 аргументами, попробуйте следующее:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements('css selector', '#live-table > div.filters > div.calendarCont > div > button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow')
```

или с использование `By.CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#live-table > div.filters > div.calendarCont > div >    button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow')
```

Кнопка нажимается путем `JS` в консоли (<kbd>F12</kbd> - dev tools) без мыши:

```
document.querySelector('#live-table > div.filters >   div.calendarCont > div >    button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow').click()
```

так что и в Python не должно быть вопросов.

В дополнению к ответу хочу сказать что по-видимому кнопка на сайте одна поэтому делать for нет смысла как и искать кнопки.

Таким образом код можно переписать как-то так:

```
driver.get("https://www.soccer24.com/")
button = driver.find_element('css selector', '#live-table > div.filters > div.calendarCont > div > button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow') 
button.Click()
```

Еще заметил у Вас разрыв между `button.` и `Click()` мне кажется Python должен на такое ругаться.

**Обновление ответа**

При тестировании кода на `Cелениуме` выяснилось что элемент не найден. Пришла идея дождаться его появления на страницы, после того как исчезнут `скелетоны` - те самые пустые квадратики, которые отображают где появятся элементы,  что я и делаю в данном решении.

Необходимы дополнительные импорты:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Код:

```
driver.get("https://www.soccer24.com/")
selector = f'''#live-table > 
div.filters > 
div.calendarCont > div > 
button.calendar__navigation.calendar__navigation--tomorrow''' 

try:
   button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
)
finally:
    pass

if (button):
    button.click()

sleep(100)
driver.quit()
```

Демонстрация работы скрипта, видео укорочено для того чтобы быть возможным опубликованным тут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет! Не работает ничего - что вы предложили.

Comment: Вы пробел убрали?

Comment: Пытаюсь запустить селектор через js driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", buttons) пишет arguments[0].click is not a function

Comment: зачем? я же написал как через js делать

Comment: пробела у меня в коде нет - это наверное кривое форматирование на сайте

Comment: как минимум эта строка точно работает, сейчас попробую проверить на селениуме

Comment: а Вы пока проверьте `print(buttons)`  что выдаст

Comment: принт выдало  []

Comment: Вы объединили 2 и 3 строку в аргументах как я советовал?

Comment: да если убрать for - выдаёт ошибку

Comment: я понял - админ снял с кнопки текстовые элементы - поэтому кнопка как будто пустая

Comment: у меня Ваши селекторы находят кнопку, так что проблема не в этом

Comment: запустил на селениуме, знаю в чем проблема ожидайте обновления вопроса. я добавлю код он должен будет работать.

Comment: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="calendar__navigation calendar__navigation--tomorrow" title="Next day">...</button> is not clickable at point (739, 301). Other element would receive the click: <div class="skOT skOT--ot">...</div>

Comment: всё )) победил с вашей помощью driver.get("https://www.soccer24.com/")
time.sleep(5)
buttons = driver.find_elements('class name', 'calendar__navigation--tomorrow')
print(buttons)

for button in buttons:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(1)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://www.soccer24.com/")
time.sleep(5)
buttons = driver.find_elements('class name', 'calendar__navigation--tomorrow')
print(buttons)

for button in buttons:
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
   time. Sleep(1)
```

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` хорошая попытка дождаться загрузки, но плохая практика, лучше использовать средства Селениума для таких случаев. Спасибо что выбрали мой ответ, я его обновил.